# Slide the entire app window to show a new menu underneath?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an app with an action bar, fragments, etc. and I want to have an extra menu available by pulling a bottom bar upwards. When it's pulled up, the whole screen should move up, revealing the menu.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably contain your main views within a layout (call it "A"), place that in a `RelativeLayout`, then place your menu ("B") behind it (so they are overlayed). When your bottom bar is dragged up, you'll have to calculate finger delta-Y positions (from `GestureDetector` or similar), and move "A" upward by that amount, leaving "B" where it is.

Be very, very careful with this though, as swiping up from the bottom of the screen on Android 4.1+ devices brings up Google Now. I would suggest instead that you use [a Sliding Menu library](https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu) (which slides in from the left instead).